# CoAP and DTLS integration

Tags: iot, network-protocols, coap, dtls, libcoap

I have implementation of CoAP (libcoap), and implementation of DTLS (tinyDTLS).
How can I make integration CoAP (libcoap) with DTLS (tinyDTLS)?

I will be grateful for the any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now supported fully in libcoap; when you build it with its submodules:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/obgm/libcoap --recursive
$ cd libcoap
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure --enable-dtls --with-tinydtls --disable-shared --disable-doxygen --disable-manpages
$ make
$ cd examples
$ ./coap-server -A ::1 -k 1234 &
$ ./coap-client 'coaps://[::1]/' -k 1234 -u CoAP
This is a test server made with libcoap (see https://libcoap.net)
Copyright (C) 2010--2016 Olaf Bergmann <bergmann@tzi.org>
```

(Tested with development `version 9184a75a21`; I added the `--disable-doxygen` line at configuration as well because those tools aren't installed here.)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to place a comment, even though this is not an answer. [Here](https://github.com/thecodemaiden/tinydtls-coap) is my attempt to do the exact same thing, using the client-server examples from both libcoap and tinydtls. Feel free to fork the code, and please sumbit a pull request if you figure out why my client and server don't finish their handshake.