# CoAPS Server, which coaps server can be used

Tags: coap, californium

1/ now, i want make libcoap client connect to a coaps server, but it cannot find a coaps server
2/ so, i neened a coaps server with psk, who can give it to me?

I have implementation of CoAP (libcoap), and implementation of DTLS (tinyDTLS). I want make libcoap client connect to a coaps server

I will be grateful for the any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Eclipse Californium](https://eclipse.org/californium) to start up your own DTLS based CoAP server.
Take a look at the [DTLS example in the source repository](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/demo-apps/sc-dtls-example-server), that should get you started.

Alternatively, you can connect to the Eclipse Californium sandbox CoAP server at californium.eclipse.org:5684.

Here's how to do that using the openssl s_client tool:

```
openssl s_client -dtls1_2 -psk_identity password -psk 736573616D65 -connect californium.eclipse.org:5684
```

Comment: hi, thx. i  want a free coaps server, not a server made by myself, i want to get a uri, such as coaps://californium.eclipse.org:5684 -u xxx -k xxx , if anyone have californium's psk name&passwd,  it would be wonderful

Answer (score 0):

You can test coaps connection local like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663736/coap-and-dtls-integration)

```
$ ./coap-server -A ::1 -k 1234 &
$ ./coap-client 'coaps://[::1]/' -k 1234 -u CoAP
```